# How can I change the a column name in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller

basically I accidentally wrote password_has instead password_hash and I thought by rake db:rollback I can make the appropriate changes and then do rake db:migrate and rake db:reset but seems like the change is not happening within mysql.. I keep getting errors.. what do I do? Ideally I want to destroy the db and restart it but it wont destroy it, because when I do and try to recreate it, it says it still has a copy already created.. I'm going nuts here, please help I'm a newbie!

Comment: rake db:rollback rollbacks only 1 last migration. show your rake db:migrate --trace

Comment: Here you go:                                                     new-host-3:shop_app vickenvartanian$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump

Answer (score 6):

You can write a rename migration. Generate it as:

```
rails g migration RenameColumn
```

Next, apply the following code in the generated migration file to rename the column:

```
 class RenameColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
  end

  def self.down
    # rename back if you need
  end
end
```

Once a migration is run, avoid rolling it back to modify. Write a new one to do that instead.

If `rake db:migrate` is giving errors, try running just the one you need as:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20130405061213
```

Just substitute the correct version (it is in the filename of your migration).x

Comment: What do you mean by generated migration files? Please be more clear, which are the generated migration files?

Comment: When you run the command `rails g migration`, a migration file is generated in `db/migrate` directory in your app. It is this file which is run upon executing `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to go back in the first place, just make a new migration changing the columns name. 
Also it would be helpful if you'd specified the error messages.

Answer (score -1):

you can execute the following sql for example:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE prev_column_name new_column_name INTEGER;
```

Comment: If you type in SQL right into a database without writing a migration, anyone else who works on the app won't have the database changes